# Linking a stackoverflow question not working as expected

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

Usually when pasting a link to a stackoverflow question (on most stackexchange sites), the site parses the url and replaces the text of the link with the question title.

For example:

When this link is pasted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353875/how-long-do-the-magento-session-files-need-to-be-kept

The text to this link would read: [How long do the magento session files need to be kept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353875/how-long-do-the-magento-session-files-need-to-be-kept)

Is this something unique to private beta sites, or is this a problem that needs to be addressed?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this is happening because the site is private so the reader (how the site picks up the title via the URL) doesn't have access to the site yet.